# How to using javascript scrollIntoView() go to id , with middle of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to using javascript `scrollIntoView()` go  to id , with middle of page ?

this code will go to id `xxx` at top page.

```
document.getElementById("xxx").scrollIntoView()
```

But i want to go to id `xxx` at middle page, Can i do that with `scrollIntoView()`

Comment: Have you checked [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView)? Even though it is not JavaScript method, I can agree with _javascript_ tag. What I really do not understand is what _jquery_ tag is doing here.

Comment: @Regent What makes you say it's not a JavaScript method? What else would it be?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist HTML DOM Element method.

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery, you can do the following:

```
var pos = $("#xxx").offset();
var top = pos.top;
var left = pos.left;
window.scrollTo((left < 0 ? 0 : left), (top < 0 ? 0 : top));
```

Comment: If your page content fits within a page (without) a scrollbar, then this will not have any effect as all parts of the page is visible. This will be prominent if there are content on the page with scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an .offset().
This link may help you:
http://pixelbar.be/blog/mit-jquery-scrollen-gewusst-wie/